# How to login in a website with phython requests?

Tags: python, post, authentication, python-requests

The registration of the website is for free: http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/login.jsp

I wrote this code to login the website based on some tutorials:

```
import requests

url = "http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/login.jsp"

# Fill in your details here to be posted to the login form.
payload = {
    'j_username': 'xxx@gmail.com',
    'j_password': 'password'
}

# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
s = request.session()
p = s.post(url, data=payload)
# print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
print p, p.url, p.status_code
print 'is redirected: ', p.is_redirect

r = s.get("https://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/msigdb/download_file.jsp?filePath=/resources/msigdb/6.2/msigdb_v6.2.xml")
# print r.text
print r, r.url, r.status_code
print 'is redirected: ', r.is_redirect

with open("lol.xml", "wb") as handle:
    handle.write(r.content)
```

I am not sure if I have to fill in the password, because it is hidden?

The post command return me back a 200 OK, but I am still not logged in:

```
<Response [200]> http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/login.jsp 200
is redirected:  False
<Response [200]> https://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/login.jsp 200
is redirected:  False
```

Ok, possible error sources are the payload with wrong dictionary keys.

The html code looks like this:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
          <table border="0" class="bodyfont" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <tbody><tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="left">Items marked with <font color="red">*</font> are required.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><h3>Email:&nbsp;<font color="red">*</font>&nbsp;</h3></td>
              <td><input id="email" type="text" name="j_username" value="">
              <input id="password" type="hidden" name="j_password" value="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="button" name="login" value="login" style="margin-top:10px;" onclick="validateForm()"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>
    </form>
```

Do I miss something? Why is not it logged in?

Comment: did you check the payload in chrome with dev tools > network. You can simply replicate it from there after a login through the browser

Comment: Using garbage credentials I get the same response: Your "success check" is faulty.

Comment: @RandomDude I cannot follow you, because I logged in and I do not get any information ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned in my comment it is a really good first step to look at the logs in the Network tab of Chrome when you want to login somewhere with requests. Your code doesn't work because you simply use the **wrong url** for your post-request! You also have some **typos in your code** e.g.: `request.session()` instead of `requests.session()`.

```
import requests


login_url = "http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/j_spring_security_check"
url = "http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/index.jsp"
payload = {
    'j_username': 'a4702585@nwytg.net',
    'j_password': 'password'
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    login = session.post(login_url, data=payload)
    req = session.get(url)
```

In general i also doubt that looking at the response status code is a good way of figuring out if the login worked or not.

1. open a session
2. sent the post request including the payload (to the right url)
3. make a get request to simulate the redirect which happens automatically in the browser (again something you learn easily by using chrome network tab)

*You can replace the url with any subdomain you want obviously...*